# ToolTip num ListView em c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Tenho um `ListView` com vários `CheckBox` criados através da base de dados.

Queria para `CheckBox` ao passar o rato por cima, me abrisse uma *tooltip* com várias informações daquele campo.

Já tentei fazer pelo evento `MouseMove`, mas não deu certo.

Código de criação da `ListView`:

```
private void Search()
{

    mUpdater = new DatabaseUpdaterService();

    mUpdater.Initialize(false, null);

    DataTable dt = mUpdater.GetVersionCheckBoxToUpdate();

    UltraListViewSubItem subItem;
    List<UltraListViewSubItem> subItemArray;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        subItemArray = new List<UltraListViewSubItem>();

        subItem = new UltraListViewSubItem();
        subItem.Value = row["Path"].ToString();
        subItemArray.Add(subItem);


        subItem = new UltraListViewSubItem();
        subItem.Value = row["LastChanged"].ToString();
        subItemArray.Add(subItem);

        subItem = new UltraListViewSubItem();
        subItem.Value = row["Path"].ToString();
        subItemArray.Add(subItem);

        UltraListViewItem item = new UltraListViewItem(
            row["Version"].ToString(), subItemArray.ToArray());
        item.Tag = (int)row["ID"];

        this.listView.Items.Add(item);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque que não usa javascript?

Comment: jquery? https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Porque isto é no trabalho, e não posso usar fora daquilo que estamos a trabalhar!

Comment: Alguma das respostas atende ao que foi pedido? Precisa de mais algo?

Comment: Não, já acabei esta parte. obrigada a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pelo que vi, tambem podes usar directamente as propriedades da classe ListView

exemplo tirado de https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.showitemtooltips(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    private ListView ListViewWithToolTips;
private void InitializeItemsWithToolTips()
{

    // Construct and set the View property of the ListView.
    ListViewWithToolTips = new ListView();
    ListViewWithToolTips.Width = 200;
    ListViewWithToolTips.View = View.List;

    // Show item tooltips.
    ListViewWithToolTips.ShowItemToolTips = true;

    // Create items with a tooltip.
    ListViewItem item1WithToolTip = new ListViewItem("Item with a tooltip");
    item1WithToolTip.ToolTipText = "This is the item tooltip.";
    ListViewItem item2WithToolTip = new ListViewItem("Second item with a tooltip");
    item2WithToolTip.ToolTipText = "A different tooltip for this item.";

    // Create an item without a tooltip.
    ListViewItem itemWithoutToolTip = new ListViewItem("Item without tooltip.");

    // Add the items to the ListView.
    ListViewWithToolTips.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{item1WithToolTip, 
        item2WithToolTip, itemWithoutToolTip} );

    // Add the ListView to the form.
    this.Controls.Add(ListViewWithToolTips);
    this.Controls.Add(button1);
}
```

Comment: ` UltraListViewSubItem subItem; List<UltraListViewSubItem> subItemArray; foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows){subItemArray = new List<UltraListViewSubItem>();subItem = new UltraListViewSubItem();subItem.Value = row["Path"].ToString();subItemArray.Add(subItem);UltraListViewItem item = new UltraListViewItem(row["Version"].ToString(),sbItemArray.ToArray());item.Tag = (int)row["ID"];this.listView.Items.Add(item);this.Invalidate();
            }`
Tenho ai o código para me criar o que vem da base de dados. E queria uma tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

Existe um componente pra isto, o [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx). Dê uma olhada na documentação linkada para ver todas as opções de configurações possíveis.

Para um funcionamento mínimo só é preciso criar uma instância dele, e atribuí-lo a um controle (ou vários).

```
var toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.SetToolTip(seuListViewItem, "Aqui vai o texto do ToolTip");
```

Answer (score 1):

Estive a verificar a pergunta que eu fiz, e vi que não coloquei aqui a resposta para quem tiver o mesmo problema que eu.

O problema que me estava a dar é porque não tinha a referência da ToolTip adicionada corretamente. 
`System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip tooltip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();`

Depois basta fazer o seguinte :

`tooltip.SetToolTip(this.btDelete, CM.GetString("Delete Version"));`